# List of ClassicCompute VMs using Azure Resource Manager library

Tags: c#, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management

Is it possible to get list of `ClassicCompute` virtual machines and manage them using Azure resource manager libraries?

VMs and storage accounts created using Azure preview portal are also of Classic version.

Is it not supported to create V2 VMs using azure preview portal or am i missing any settings?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the Azure preview Portal has been recently updated to allow you to choose if you want "classic" vms or vms using the new ARM templates.

**To do this:**

Goto "New", select your template such as "Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter", and in the drop down box above the "Create" command button, there is a section titled "Select a compute stack." This will let you select "Use the Service Management stack (classic)" - (ie V1 classic compute) or "Use the Resource Manager Stack" - (ie V2 classic compute).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Azure preview portal support both V1 and V2 VMs. You can create a V2 VM using Browse All -> Virtual Machines, and create a V1 VM using Browse All -> Virtual Machines (classic)

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a way to achieve this via .Net library

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of V1 & V2 VMs using the code below. `ListRecursiveAsync()` is just an extension method I threw together to deal with the possibility of more than one page of results.

Also for understanding the capabilities of the ARM API in general, the [Azure Resource Explorer)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-resource-explorer-a-new-tool-to-discover-the-azure-api/) is a great tool.

```
    using (var client = new ResourceManagementClient(creds))
    {
        var v1ComputeParams = new ResourceListParameters { ResourceType = "Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines" };
        var v2ComputeParams = new ResourceListParameters { ResourceType = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" };

        var v1ComputeResult = await client.ListRecursiveAsync(v1ComputeParams, null);
        var v2ComputeResult = await client.ListRecursiveAsync(v2ComputeParams, null);
    }

/// <summary>
/// Gets the list of resources, recursing until ResourceListResult.NextLink is empty. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="client"></param>
/// <param name="parameters">Optional. Query parameters. If null is passed returns all resources from all resource groups.</param>
/// <param name="nextLink"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static async Task<IList<GenericResourceExtended>> ListRecursiveAsync(this ResourceManagementClient client, ResourceListParameters listParams, string nextLink)
{
    var rValue = new List<GenericResourceExtended>();

    ResourceListResult computeList = null;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nextLink))
    {
        computeList = await client.Resources.ListNextAsync(nextLink);
    }
    else
    {
        computeList = await client.Resources.ListAsync(listParams);
    }

    rValue.AddRange(computeList.Resources);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(computeList.NextLink))
    {
        var nextResult = await ListRecursiveAsync(client, null, computeList.NextLink);
        rValue.AddRange(nextResult);
    }

    return rValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps to some extend. But I am looking for a way to manage classic VM like deploy, edit, power on etc. looks like i still have to use classic compute libraries.

Comment: @pravn757 that's correct, afaik. It looks like the Azure Resource Explorer has been updated since I posted this - there are a number of new capabilities included there.

Comment: It does look like the v2+ SDK is slowly moving to support more of the v1 service management schema; breaking changes in the latest ARM SDK bits from last year seem to be incorporating changes required to unify v1 & v2 provisioning/management